Film about a monkey on a train in India 1960s 1970s?
Does anyone have a suggestion about what this film might be called?

it's set on a steam train in India, a passenger train
I think it's from the 1970s? Not entirely sure, could be earlier
colour film, live action
I think it's mainly about a monkey, who I remember running along the roof of the train

I think the entirety of the film is set on the train and about the train going through variously landscapes, with the camera often on top of the train filming its journey 
Maybe the monkey steals food from the restaurant car
Also i remember it being very dusty
And I think the main human character is a young boy 
I really have vague memories as I watched it as a child. 
Any suggestions would be great.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
